# SQL Unique Values

Tags: sql, join, informix, duplicate-data

I have this query that joins 3 table. It appears to be working but I am getting duplicates. How can I remove the duplicates?

```
SELECT FIRST 100 e.email_id, e.location_id, e.email, l.location_type, p.salutation,
       p.fname, p.lname
FROM email e, location l, person p
WHERE e.location_id = l.location_id
AND l.per_id = p.per_id
```

Comment: Which version of Informix are you using?  You should be able to use the SQL-92 explicit join notations instead of the implicit joins that you're using - unless you have a really old version of Informix (OnLine 5.20, SE 7.2x).  You should also use the explicit joins in preference to the Informix-style OUTER join - I saw that in a question of yours which you have now deleted.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The simple answer is to add DISTINCT to your query.

```
SELECT FIRST 100 DISTINCT e.email_id, e.location_id, e.email, l.location_type, p.salutation, p.fname, p.lname
FROM email e, location l, person p
WHERE e.location_id = l.location_id
AND l.per_id = p.per_id
```

Comment: Adding DISTINCT just keeps it running forever even if I do SELECT FIRST 2

Comment: That's because the engine has to scan all rows to perform the de-duplication before returning any to the client. The FIRST N clause isn't going to achieve very much in this instance.

Answer (score 2):

use Distinct

```
  SELECT FIRST 100 Distinct e.email_id, e.location_id, 
         e.email, l.location_type, p.salutation, 
         p.fname, p.lname 
  FROM email e, location l, person p 
  WHERE e.location_id = l.location_id AND l.per_id = p.per_id
```

Answer (score 2):

Since you are doing straight inner joins, you only get duplicate entries in the result set if there are duplicate entries in the input tables.

```
SELECT FIRST 100 e.email_id, e.location_id, e.email, l.location_type, p.salutation,
       p.fname, p.lname
  FROM email AS e
  JOIN location AS l ON e.location_id = l.location_id
  JOIN person AS p ON l.per_id = p.per_id
```

The most likely place for there to be trouble is in the 'location' table.  You could establish that with a query such as:

```
SELECT location_id, per_id, COUNT(*)
  FROM location
 GROUP BY location_id, per_id
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1;
```

If this returns any data, then you have a pointer to where the trouble is.  You should then examine why you don't have a unique constraint on the combination of location_id, per_id.